# Run custom code when adding to Many-To-One relation

Tags: django, django-models, overriding, django-queryset, django-managers

```
from django.db import models

class Reporter(models.Model):
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

Now whenever I add an article to a reporter (like below) I want to run some custom code, what method should I override (without changing `bulk=True`)?

```
>>> new_article = Article.objects.create()
>>> new_reporter = Reporter.objects.create()
>>> new_reporter.article_set.add(new_article, bulk=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer will depend on how you create objects on your application, this will run the code the FIRST time an Article is added to a reporter

```
class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.reporter:
            if not self.reporter.article__set: 
                #do your code here
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will run the code if the Article on the reporter is changing

```
class Article(models.Model):
    reporter = models.ForeignKey(Reporter, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.reporter:
            if not self.reporter.article__set is self: 
                #do your code here
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Haven't tested it but the logic seems sound

Comment: The save method isn't executed when running the example I provided

Comment: @OskarPersson the create method is a shortcut to creating and saving, also creating the Article without a reporter should give an error

Comment: You're right, it should. I updated the Article model with the reporter field being nullable.

Comment: @OskarPersson so, the solution would depend on how you create objects in your database, I'll update the answer

Comment: Once again, the save method isn't executed when running the example I provided. This doesn't work.

Comment: @OskarPersson unless you ovewrote the `create` method, it calls `save`, you have to call save in order for changes to take effect in your database.

Comment: But I want it to trigger whenever I **add to the relation**. This could be long after the creation of both objects and doesn't call `save`

Comment: @OskarPersson it does actually, any change made in an object needs to be saved in order to take effect in the database. Save is not called only on creation

Comment: [Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) is the documentation for `add` stating otherwise. _Note: I can't change bulk=True_

Comment: @OskarPersson that's only with m2m as it says there, because the save method is called on the intermediary table, also it says how to listen to changes in m2m relationships

Comment: The example and the two lines following it are **clearly** talking about a Many-To-One relation. "In the example above, in the case of a ForeignKey relationship, QuerySet.update() is used to perform the update". And as the documentation for [`QuerySet.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update) says: "Finally, realize that update() does an update at the SQL level and, thus, does not call any save() methods on your models, nor does it emit the pre_save or post_save signals (which are a consequence of calling Model.save())"

Comment: @OskarPersson I see now, well is there a reason you want to use add? It seems that add is specifically aimed at being faster and not needing to save, which sounds like is what you need

Comment: Well, I need the speed.

Comment: @OskarPersson I think it's safe to say it is not possible at the moment, listeners will always hinder speed, you can always make a trigger at the db level which will also hinder speed